# Google Map v3 Map loaded event

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Is there any listener to handle map completely loaded?

In my case, I need to get bounds from map, so I've done it this way:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, "bounds_changed", this.mapLoaded);

mapLoaded: function() {
    google.maps.event.clearListeners(this.map, "bounds_changed");

    var bounds = this.map.getBounds();

    this.collection.setBounds(bounds.getNorthEast(), bounds.getSouthWest());
    this.collection.fetch();
},
```

Is there any not-hacking way?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Try something like:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
    //loaded fully
});
```

Answer (score 19):

How about the `tilesloaded`event?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
  // Visible tiles loaded!
});
```